# jQuery horizontal slidding gallery not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a jQuery sliding video gallery, but it isn't quite doing what I want. Rather than scroll through the images when I click my arrow buttons, it moves the entire div right/left depending on the direction.

HTML:

```
<div id="videocontainer">
  <a href="#" class="backward"><img src="images/backwards.png" width="30" height="27" /></a>
  <div class="videogallery">
    <ul>
      <li><a href=""><img src="thumbnails.jpg" />video1<span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="thumbnails.jpg" />video2<span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="thumbnails.jpg" />vidoe3<span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="forward"><img src="images/forward.png" width="30" height="27" /></a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.forward').click(function() {
    $('.videogallery').animate({
      marginLeft: "+=200"
    }, "fast");
  });
  $('.backward').click(function() {
    $('.videogallery').animate({
      marginLeft: "-=200"
    }, "fast");
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#videocontainer {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:160px;
}
.backward {
  background-image:url(images/backward.png);
  margin-top:50px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}
.forward {
  background-image:url(images/forward.png);
  margin-top:-30px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
ul a {
  padding-right: 32px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #371C1C;
}
.videogallery {
  width:100%;
  zoom:1;
}
.videogallery span{ display:block; }
.videogallery a{
  display:-moz-inline-stack;
  display:inline-block;
  zoom:1;
  *display:inline;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px;
  width:180px;
  border:solid 1px #b8b8b8;
  background-color:#f4f5f5;
  font-family:Trebuchet,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:11px;
  font-weight:normal;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
  opacity:0.87;
}
```

Now I am using videolightbox for the videos, but that works find and should be irrelevant. Basically I would like to turn this into a carosel and I'm sure its something fairly simple that needs to be adjusted, but I'm still a newb and trying to learn.

Comment: But you are animating the div '.videogallery', so thats why the div is moving.

Comment: well the videogallery div would be the div that contains the main content

Answer (score 0):

i pretty much got it figured out. I added a class to the href links in the ul and it did the trick.